# Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/objectSpread2'

Tags: reactjs

```js
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "firebase": "^9.0.2",
    "firebase-tools": "^9.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.15.4"
  }
}
```

while running npm run build this error popup I tried to install babelcore and runtime manually but it didn't fixed it. Is there any way to fix this??
please help me.
thanks in advance:)

Comment: Add code snippets not images

Comment: sry i am new to this I didn't knew that there is code snippet feature. Also can u please tell me which file should I add package.json or package-lock.json(because this file is too long) and i am confused which should add to the code snippet

Comment: When that kind of situation happens try to remove the `node_modules` folder and install packages again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this problem today when updating all our dependencies.
We configure webpack ourselves and aren't running a vanilla Create-React-App setup so our environments are different to yours.

For what it's worth...
I installed the dependency and tried turning it off an on again, seemed to do the trick.

1. Explicitly declare the @babel/runtime in package.json file

   ```
   "devDependencies": {
       ....other dependencies,
       "@babel/runtime": "^7.15.4",
   }
   ```
2. Delete the package-lock.json file
3. Re-install dependencies

   ```
   npm install
   ```

Error went away, your set up might be different with create-react-app so I hope this works for you too!

Comment: Actually my error got fixed I just cloned my project from github repo and installed the npm and then I tried there was no error it went away. Anyway Thanks Man for suggesting this solution it will be useful for me in future.